# Vaadin22 dosen't return value for expression

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

When i call `UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("document.getElementById("test").scrollTop")`
the `PendingJavaScriptResult` always returns null. No error is given through the error handler. When i execute the javascript in the console of the browser everything works fine.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try adding 'return' to your Javascript call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have `"return document.getElementById("test").scrollTop"` as the JavaScript expression. Otherwise you're just returning nothing.

Comment: This is so simple. Why didn't i think of this